# Is there any browser based IDE alternative to Eclipse CHE?

Tags: ide, eclipse

I need browser based IDE which can be self-hosted. In which popular programming compiler/interpreter should be available, such as java, python, c, c++, etc.,
Eclipse che is little overkill for this much requirement, and also i cant afford that much memory which is consumed by single che instance.